# RxJs - Default error handler when no subscriber handles error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm looking for an *overridable default* error handler for RxJs in my Angular 6 application. Looking for the following behavior

**my-service.ts**

```js
getArticle(id: string) {
  return this.http.get<Article>(`/api/articles/${id}`).pipe(
    defaultHandler(err => {
      console.log('Default error handler', err);
      // TODO Show dialog saying: err.data.msgFromServer || 'Unknown error'
    })
  );
}
```

**CASE 1: No subscriber handles error**

```js
myService.getArticle('1234').pipe(map(...), ...otherOperators)
  .subscribe(this.onNext); // Default error handler HttpErrorResponse {...}
```

**CASE 2: At least one subscriber handles error**

```js
myService.getArticle('1234').pipe(map(...), ...otherOperators)
  .subscribe(this.onNext, err => console.log('Hi from subscriber'));
// Hi from subscriber
```

Comment: RxJS doesn't work like that. Notifications are pushed from sources to sinks and sources will not know whether or not sinks listen for next, error or complete notifications. If an error notification is emitted without a handler in place, the error is thrown (asynchronously) as unhandled and the source has no way of knowing that. Also, with the cold observable examples in your question, there is a one-to-one relationship between sources and sinks - so there is no "at least one" situation.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `handleError()` is an example of default Error handler for your http interceptor. 
It handles general http errors here and sends its parameter(`'Error Occured'`) to anywhere you subscribed `postCall()`.

```
export class Http extends HttpClient {

   constructor(httpHandler: HttpHandler) {
      super(httpHandler);
   }

   postCall(url: string, body, options?): Observable<any> {
      return super.post(url, body, options)
          .pipe(
             tap(response => { console.log(response) }),
             catchError(this.handleError('Error Occured')));
             // 'Error Occured' or anything here goes to anywhere you subscribe postCall() as response
   }

  private handleError<T>(result?: T) {
     return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
        console.error('Status: ', error.status); // Example output 'Status: 401'
        return of(result as T);
     };
  }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want `handleError` to be triggered if some subscriber subscribes with an error callback. In this case it would be triggered regardless.

Comment: This way it always triggers handleError() but you can use this approche for handling your general Error and handle specific error by sending error parameter instead of 'Error Occurred' string to subscriber and and handle it in subscriber.

Comment: Look at the last line ---> handleError() returns result as T to subscriber.